# pip install cgal-bindings - missing the gmp, mpfr, CGAL library

Tags: python, anaconda, cgal

I am trying to install `cgal-bindings` but get the following error

```
pip install cgal-bindings

Collecting cgal-bindings
  Using cached cgal-bindings-1.2.tar.gz (1.7 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 255:
     command: /home_nfs/haziq/cenvs/ikeaclean/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hwua7alp/cgal-bindings_851231877da54c81a5ca4be83846a665/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hwua7alp/cgal-bindings_851231877da54c81a5ca4be83846a665/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-962zx6aq
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-hwua7alp/cgal-bindings_851231877da54c81a5ca4be83846a665/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    You are missing the gmp library
    You are missing the mpfr library
    You are missing the CGAL library
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/3a/900cf320705e4fe155d1f5b217ed4565e2735a93e2ec75e9d32c848d779f/cgal-bindings-1.2.tar.gz#sha256=1d50303450149c112d04231284f2b5d2a69218d0e261c11a8265bbb00692aaac (from https://pypi.org/simple/cgal-bindings/). Command errored out with exit status 255: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

even after I installed the missing libraries

```
conda install -c anaconda gmp
conda install -c conda-forge mpfr
conda install -c conda-forge cgal
```

What should I do ?

I am able to import CGAL but somehow running `pip install cgal-bindings` continues to tell me that I am missing the CGAL library.

```
(/home_nfs/haziq/cenvs/ikea) haziq@coffeemaker:~$ python
Python 3.9.0 (default, Nov 15 2020, 14:28:56)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import CGAL
```

Comment: are you using different virtualenvs?

Comment: @drum no i am in the same anaconda environment for all the steps

Comment: Did you check this out? https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/wiki/Installation

Comment: I thought the conda package was called cgal-cpp and not cgal.